# Prevent inflating every time on custom dialogs

Tags: android

I have searched and searched about this but I unfortunately didn't found any useful information about how to reuse a previously inflated view on a custom dialog.

This is what I've tried (None of them worked)

**Approach 1:**

Keep my alertdialog builder as global and within `onCreate()` do what I need:

```
private AlertDialog.Builder dialog;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        detailView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.detail, null);
        TextView textview1 = (TextView)detailView.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
        TextView textview2 = (TextView)detailView.findViewById(R.id.lblSubtitle);

        textview1.setText("Test1");
        textview2.setText("Test2");
        dialog.setView(detailView);
        dialog.create();

    btnSearch = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    }
```

And then just show it when I need it: `dialog.show();`

Didn't work, LogCat output:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. 
You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

**Approach 2:**

At `onCreate()` just inflate the layout and in the click event:

```
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    TextView textview1 = (TextView)detailView.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
    TextView textview2 = (TextView)detailView.findViewById(R.id.lblSubtitle);
    textview1.setText("Test1");
    textview2.setText("Test2");
    dialog.setView(detailView);
    dialog.create();
```

But it crashed giving the same error output.

Of course I've read the output and tried to find the parent, so I guessed the parent would be the dialog itself, but it doesn't have any method to remove views, so I don't really know what to do.

Also is there a way to reuse the textview references?

(I know it's poorly coded, just want to get it working and I'll get it properly refactored.

Comment: Are you particular about it being an alert dialog? Because it doesn't look like you want it to be interactable, in which case you can go ahead and use a custom `Toast dialog = new Toast(Activity)` to achieve what you want

Comment: It won't be interactive at all, it'll just display information but a Toast won't be enough because I'll display complex controls (imageviews, lists).

Comment: also, using the second parameter in the inflate() might help too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it:

The problem was the following:

I was trying to show an `AlertDialog.Builder` not an `AlertDialog`. I have no idea of what I was thinking when I declared it as `dialog`.

I just declared an AlertDialog and assigned the result of `builder.create()` and now it's working as intented, inflating just once.

Thank you a lot, guys, specially to @Laurence Dawson, his answer made me realize that my code was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you cancel or dismiss the Dialog, you need to remove the inflated view. The following code does this:

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    try{
      ((FrameLayout)detailView.getParent()).removeView(detailView);
    }catch(Exception e){
      //todo handle the case detailView doesn't have a parent
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can re-add your detailView to a new Dialog.

Comment: It's not the answer but I upvote you because your answer made me realize that I didn't name my objects correctly. So it was TOTALLY useful.

Because I was trying to set the OnDismissListener on my "dialog" which was actually a AlertDialog.Builder.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I would mark this as correct as it will be useful for others to see how to remove the custom views of a dialog.